# How do I return a 404 page for pages beyond category pagination pages?

Tags: 404-page, pagination, pager

That title sounds confusing, sorry.

But basically I have a category grid page, with pagination.

So I have pages like:

```
/men/tops/shirts.html
/men/tops/shirts.html?p=2
/men/tops/shirts.html?p=3
```

This is all fine and good, but if I do this:

```
/men/tops/shirts.html?p=987654
```

That URL will load the last available page of products. How do I instead make this return a 404 error?

Basically I need to do this for Infinite Scroll's sake. Otherwise my infinite scroll keeps loading the last page of products and never ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom controller, you can add

```
$this->_forward('noRoute')
```